# Как в Android можно отловить Intent BroadcastReceiver-ом, который отлавливается OnNewIntent()

Tags: android, android-intent

В Андроид есть такая проблема, что есть некоторые **intent**, которые отлавливаются **OnNewIntent()**, но если настроить в **BroadcastReceiver** **intentFilter** на **intent** с нужным нам **Action**, он туда всё равно не заходит, но прекрасно отловится **OnNewIntent()**. Есть ли какой способ отлавливать любой **Intent** в сервисе?

Comment: например, какой интент?

Comment: Например, Intent с Action равным ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED